# Difference between minima of L1-regularized quadratics

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, convex, matrix-calculus

How can I find

$$F(A,b,x,c)=\inf_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n}(\theta^{\top}A\theta+b^\top\theta+x^\top\theta+c||\theta||_1)-\inf_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n}(\theta^{\top}A\theta+b^\top\theta-x^\top\theta+c||\theta||_1)?$$

(Note the sign in front of $x^\top\theta$.)
$x, b,\theta$ are vectors; $c>0$ is a scalar; $A$ is a positive definite matrix. $||\theta||_1=\sum_{r=1}^n |\theta_r|$. In order to solve the above one may require to use subdifferential since absolute values are not differentiable.

An approximation with some guarantee is good enough for me.

**Known case**

By using Harville, 1997, Matrix Algebra From a Statistician's Perspective  Theorem 19.1.1:

$$F(A,b,x)=\inf_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n}(\theta^{\top}A\theta+b^\top\theta+x^\top\theta)-\inf_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n}(\theta^{\top}A\theta+b^\top\theta-x^\top\theta)=-b^\top A^{-1}x.$$

**Notes**

My function is as follows:

$F(\sum_{t=1}^Tx_tx_t^{\top},-2\sum_{t=1}^{T-1}y_tx_t^{\top},2Yx_T^{\top},a)$

where $a>0$, $x,y,Y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Maybe this coincides with the LASSO problem. I was hoping to get a closed form, which I don't think is possible, perhaps just to show that my problem is exactly like LASSO problem might be good. The issue is LASSO does not has a dual form. Maybe applying Online Gradient Descent Algorithm to this may work. I will work on that.

For the case when we have $a||\theta||_2^2$, we obtain:

$\frac{1}{4Y}{F(aI+\sum_{t=1}^Tx_tx_t^{\top},-2\sum_{t=1}^{T-1}y_tx_t^{\top},2Yx_T^{\top})}$

$=\frac{1}{4Y}F(aI+\sum_{t=1}^Tx_tx_t^{\top},-2\sum_{t=1}^{T-1}y_tx_t^{\top},2Yx_T^{\top})$

$=(\sum_{t=1}^{T-1}y_tx_t^{\top})(aI+\sum_{t=1}^Tx_tx_t^{\top})^{-1} x_T\;\;\;$

Which I guess is the dual form for ridge regression, maybe I can show similarly that my Problem is of LASSO. But for now the problem seems to be of difference of two LASSO.

**What If**

$F(A,b,x)=\inf_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n}(\frac{\theta^{\top}A\theta}{||\theta||_1}+b^\top\theta+x^\top\theta)-\inf_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n}(\frac{\theta^{\top}A\theta}{||\theta||_1}+b^\top\theta-x^\top\theta)=?$

Comment: Are you looking for an analytic bound on $F$, an algorithm to approximate it for particular inputs, or what? I doubt a closed form is available, though of course I might be wrong.

Comment: Closed form is the best, but if you can suggest an approximate solution with some error bound that will be great.

Comment: So, unlike in the known case, there is no known closed-form solution to each of the subproblems (if there were, LASSO problems would be solvable in closed-form, but they're not). This doesn't *necessarily* mean there's not a closed form for the difference, but it definitely makes it harder.

Comment: Can you please tell what is the closed for for LASSO problem?

Comment: But this is not a Lasso problem so maybe it is possible to obtain one in this case

Comment: Lasso is $\min \theta^\top (X^\top X) \theta - 2 (y^\top X) \theta + N \lambda \lVert \theta \rVert_1$, which can be the first half of your problem with $A = X^\top X$, $b + x = X^\top y$, $c = N \lambda$. If you could solve the halves of your problem in closed form, you could solve Lasso in closed form, which many people have tried and failed to do. Of course, you don't need to solve either half; you need the difference. Maybe you can do that: it's *something* like bounding the difference in Lasso solutions as you change the labels, but a little more general.

Comment: I doubt I will be able to solve. But thank you for your comments.

Comment: @Dougal I had a look at the paper On the LASSO and its dual. I didn't understand how I can apply that to my case, can you help me with that?

Comment: @Dougal I have added few comments(in particular **what if** bit). Does the problem becomes a bit easier?

Comment: As long as $T>n$ you should be able to use the lasso equivalence from my answer. I don't know what you mean by lasso not having a dual; I use it in my answer. The "what if" part is pretty different and I'm not sure what it'd look like without going through it; you could try deriving the dual yourself and seeing.

Comment: @Dougal I meant it was difficult for me to get a dual of Lasso like it is presented  [here](http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/258942/1/Dualrr_ICML98.pdf). I will try to understand your work possibly by doing so things will become more clear.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not a full answer yet, but it makes some progress.*

Define$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\tp}{^\mathsf{T}}$
$$G(A, d, c) := \inf_{\theta \in \R^n} \theta\tp A \theta + d\tp \theta + c \lVert \theta \rVert_1,$$
so that
$$
F(A, b, x, c) = G(A, b + x, c) - G(A, b - x, c)
.$$

Note that the Lasso problem can be written as
$$
L(X, y, \lambda)
= \inf_{\beta \in \R^n} \tfrac12 \lVert y - X \beta \rVert^2 + \lambda \lVert \beta \rVert_1
= G(\tfrac12 X\tp X, X\tp y, \lambda)
.$$

Suppose that $A$ is full-rank, and define $L$ to be its Cholesky decomposition such that $R\tp R = A$; $R$ will be invertible. Then we can turn $G(A, d, c)$ into $L(X, y, \lambda)$ if:
\begin{gather}
\tfrac12 X\tp X = A \quad\text{i.e. } X = \sqrt{2} R \\
X\tp y = d \quad\text{i.e.} \sqrt{2} R\tp y = d \quad\text{i.e. } y = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} R^{-\mathsf T} d \\
\lambda = c
.\end{gather}
So, as long as $A$ is full-rank, we have
$$
F(A, b, x, c) = L\left(\sqrt 2 R, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} R^{-\mathsf T} ( b + x ), \lambda \right) - L\left(\sqrt 2 R, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} R^{-\mathsf T} ( b - x ), \lambda \right)
.$$

Thus, since $R$ is full-rank, your problem is equivalent to considering
$$
L(X, y, \lambda) - L(X, z, \lambda)
.$$

---

By setting up the problem
$$
\inf_{\beta \in \R^n, z \in \R^n \text{ s.t. } z = A x} \tfrac12 \lVert y - z \rVert^2 + \lambda \lVert \beta \rVert_1
$$
and using strong duality, we can derive that (see e.g. page 2 of [these notes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/scribes/10725_Lecture17.pdf))
\begin{gather}
L(X, y, \lambda) = \sup_{u \in C} \tfrac12 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \lVert y - u \rVert^2, \\ \text{where  }
C = \{ u \in \R^n : \lVert X\tp u \rVert_\infty \le \lambda \}
  = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \{ u : X_i\tp u \le \lambda \} \cap \{ u : X_i\tp u \ge -\lambda \} \tag{*}
\end{gather}
is a polyhedron depending on $X$ and $\lambda$ but (luckily) independent of $y$. Note also that $C = \lambda X^{-\mathsf T} \{ v : \lVert v \rVert_\infty \le 1 \}$, i.e. it is the image of the unit hypercube under the linear map $\lambda X^{-\mathsf T}$ (or the preimage of the unit hypercube under $\frac1\lambda X\tp$).

We can use this form to say that
\begin{align}
L(X, y, \lambda) - L(X, z, \lambda)
&= 
\sup_{u \in C}\left[ \tfrac12 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \lVert y - u \rVert^2 \right]
- \sup_{u \in C}\left[ \tfrac12 \lVert z \rVert^2 - \lVert z - u \rVert^2 \right]
\\&= \tfrac12 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \tfrac12 \lVert z \rVert^2 - \inf_{u \in C} \lVert y - u \rVert^2 + \inf_{u \in C} \lVert z - u \rVert^2
\\&= \tfrac12 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \tfrac12 \lVert z \rVert^2 - \lVert y - \Pi_C(y) \rVert^2 + \lVert z - \Pi_C(z) \rVert^2
,\end{align}
where $\Pi_C$ denotes projection onto $C$.

Polyhedra are convex, so we know that $\lVert \Pi_C(y) - \Pi_C(z) \rVert \le \lVert y - z \rVert$, but that doesn't quite get us there.

Note from (*) that $\Pi_C(y)$ will end up being the same as the projection of $y$ onto *some* hyperplane $X_i\tp u = \pm \lambda$, though we don't know which one. But then 
$$
\Pi_C(y) = y + \frac{\pm\lambda - X_i\tp y}{\lVert X_i \rVert^2} X_i
\qquad\text{so}\qquad
\lVert y - \Pi_C(y) \rVert^2 = \frac{(\pm\lambda - X_i\tp y)^2}{\lVert X_i \rVert^2}
.$$

Now, if $y$ and $z$ project onto the *same* face of $C$ – which is likely if $y$ and $z$ are "close" – then we get
\begin{align}
L(X, y, \lambda) - L(X, z, \lambda)
&= \tfrac12 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \tfrac12 \lVert z \rVert^2
- \frac{(X_i\tp y \pm\lambda)^2}{\lVert X_i \rVert^2}
+ \frac{(X_i\tp z \pm\lambda)^2}{\lVert X_i \rVert^2}
\\&= \tfrac12 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \tfrac12 \lVert z \rVert^2
- \frac{(X_i\tp y)^2 - (X_i\tp z)^2 \pm 2 \lambda X_i\tp (y - z)}{\lVert X_i \rVert^2}
\\&= \tfrac12 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \tfrac12 \lVert z \rVert^2
- \frac{X_i\tp (y-z) \; X_i\tp (y + z)}{\lVert X_i \rVert^2}
\mp 2 \lambda \left( \frac{X_i}{\lVert X_i \rVert^2}\right)\tp (y - z)
\\&= \tfrac12 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \tfrac12 \lVert z \rVert^2
- \tilde X_i\tp (y-z) \; \tilde X_i\tp (y + z)
\mp 2 \lambda \frac{1}{\lVert X_i \rVert} \tilde X_i \tp (y - z)
\end{align}
where $\tilde X_i = X_i / \lVert X_i \rVert$.
We can at least loosely bound this with Cauchy-Schwarz as
\begin{align}
\left\lvert L(X, y, \lambda) - L(X, z, \lambda) \right\rvert
&\le \left\lvert \tfrac12 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \tfrac12 \lVert z \rVert^2 \right\rvert
+ \lVert y - z \rVert \lVert y + z \rVert
+ \frac{2 \lambda \lVert y - z \rVert}{\min_i \lVert X_i \rVert}
\\&\le
\tfrac32 \lVert y - z \rVert \lVert y + z \rVert
+ \frac{2 \lambda \lVert y - z \rVert}{\min_i \lVert X_i \rVert}
.\end{align}
But remember that this bound only **probably** holds when $y$ and $z$ are "close," so that they probably hit the same facet – I'm not sure how to quantify that.

The dependence on $\min_i \lVert X_i \rVert$ can probably be improved, since probably constraints like $X_i\tp u \le \lambda$ are more likely to be active when $\lVert X_i \rVert$ is big.

Plugging into your original variables, we have $y - z = \sqrt 2 R^{-\mathsf T} x$, $y + z = \sqrt 2 R^{-\mathsf T} b$, $\min_i \lVert X_i \rVert = \min_i \sqrt{ 2 \sum_j R_{ij}^2 }$. Loosening the bound again we get that "probably", for "small" $x$: 
$$
\left\lvert L(X, y, \lambda) - L(X, z, \lambda) \right\rvert
\le
3 \lVert A^{-1} \rVert_2 \lVert x \rVert \lVert b \rVert
+ \frac{2 \lambda \sqrt{\lVert A^{-1} \rVert_2} \lVert x \rVert}{\min_i \lVert R_{i,\cdot} \rVert}
,$$
where $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ is the operator norm (the largest eigenvalue), and probably the row norms of $R$ have some meaning in terms of $A$ but I don't know what.